# VBA, what is the purpose of the equal sign within quotes for an auto filter or in general?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have noticed this syntax a couple of times when people are talking about using autfilter in VBA, I am confused on the purpose of the `="=Brian*"` part, I understand that `*` is a wildcard, but I am confused on the purpose of the equal sign within the quotes. This was one example I found of it being used. Any idea what that equal sign in the quotes is actually doing?

```
with activesheet.cells(1, 1).currentregion
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=Brian*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*John"
end with
```

Comment: If you will see it against "<>Brian*", will it become clearer...?

Comment: @FaneDuru, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean that `AutoFilter` can do its job  for all cells **being equal to "Brian"**, or for cells **not being equal to "Brian"**...

Comment: Think of `=` as "matches" and `<>` as "doesn't match"

Comment: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b

Answer (score 0):

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=Brian*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*John"
```

means cells which starts with Brian or ends with John. after filtering the column will contain all the cells either starting with Brian or ending with John

```
Criteria1:="Criteria"
```

In the double quotations a criteria is entered and here the criteria is all cells equal to Brian* which can be written as

```
=Brian*
```

Comment: so basically "=Brian*" and "Brian*" are the same thing in the eyes of the compiler?

Comment: = is a default operator in cases where you have to check equality, but for the cases where you have to apply other operators like not equal to or less than etc, they have to be written so writing = is a good thing